# Clarification on fundamental theorem of calculus as explained in wikipedia

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

[in the wikipedia page for the fundamental theorem of calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Geometric_meaning)
it is explained the geometric meaning of the theorem, I'm having trouble understanding where does [the first part of this inequality comes from](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNPgP.jpg),
just by re-arranging the terms shouldn't it be:

$ \left| f(x)-\frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h} \right|= \frac {|\text{Red Excess}|}{h} \leq...$

Instead of:

$ \left| f(x)-\frac{A(x+h)-A(x)}{h} \right| \leq \frac {|\text{Red Excess}|}{h} \leq...$

It's probably something silly i'm missing, but i cant seem to quite get what it is.

Comment: You seem to be ignoring the significance of the absolute value signs in the part of the page that you have highlighted.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that up!.
I have probably forgotten some relevant algebra linking absolute values and inequalities then? looking up absolute value equations on khan academy would clear things up?. I'm not quite sure what's going on with those absolute values.

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan The left-hand side is wrapped within absolute value; but other than that, you are correct, the first comparison is an equality. This is immaterial to the geometric explanation, but you are right.

Comment: lol - and I just went on Wikipedia and made that change. Now it says =.

Comment: (And I just noticed you have a minus sign in the first formula....which shouldn't be there.) I will edit to correct everything so your post makes sense.

Comment: that minus sign on the right hand side goes away because of the use of the absolute value, right?